# Orbital Component Abbreviations

Tags: orbital-elements

I'm currently in the process of writing an SDK for the [ESA's DISCOSweb API](https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/). I've come across these attributes on Orbital details.

```
"inc": 52.0,
"raan": 0.0,
"epoch": "1999-10-22",
"sma": 7791700.0,
"ecc": 0.00011,
"aPer": 0.0,
"mAno": null,
"frame": "J2000"
```

I can figure out what most of these are:

| Abbreviation | Long Form |
| --- | --- |
| inc | Inclination |
| raan | Right Ascension of Ascending Node |
| epoch | Epoch/Time |
| sma | Semi-major Axis |
| ecc | Eccentricity |
| aPer | **Unknown** |
| mAno | **Unknown** |
| frame | Frame |

Does anyone know what the two unknown abbreviations refer to?

Comment: argument of periapsis and mean anomaly. Also "raan" is Right Ascension of the Ascending Node, sometimes also called longitude of the ascending node

Comment: @AlfonsoGonzalez - Thanks bud, want to put that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm curious: Do these numbers represent a real object, and if so, which object? It seems odd that mean anomaly at epoch is NULL

Answer (score 4):

Argument of periapsis and mean anomaly. Also "raan" is Right Ascension of the Ascending Node, sometimes also called longitude of the ascending node

@notovny brings up a good point that its odd that mean anomaly is null, since eccentricity isn't zero so there isn't an ambiguity for AOP or true / mean anomaly.